# Rails: Save and update data in the DB programatically based on another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm using Rails 3 and mongoid.

I want to save, or update, a value in one record based off of a value in another record.

For example:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :account_level, :type => Integer
end


class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :position, :type => Integer
end
```

If the `account_level` in User is 1 then `position` in Profile should be updated to 1 also. If `account_level is 2, then`position` should be 2.

This should be done programmatically without input from the user or using an invisible input field on the client (there must be a better way to do it than that).

Extra question...what is I had the following logic (for `position`), how would I do this?

`account_level` 1 = `position` 1
`account_level` 2 = `position` 1
`account_level` 3 = `position` 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question.

Try with callbacks ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html ):

For example, in User class:

```
before_save :set_equals_account_level_and_position
def set_equals_account_level_and_position
  profile.position = account_level
  profile.save!
end
```

Comment: Look like you did understand it. What about if the profile.position wasn't a 1:1 relation to account_level. Is there a way to save different values base on some sort of logic (this is the "extra question") part of the question.

Comment: If it's not 1:1 relation, what kind of relation? What do you mean by *sort of logic*?

Comment: For example, if I want `account_level` with a value of 1 and 2 to translate into `position` with a value of 1, or `account_level` with a value of 3 to translate into a `position` with value of 5.